# mdframed: how to manage footnotes in the case of two embedded mdframes environments?

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

### Question

My question is about the behavior of `mdframed` with footnotes. I have two embedded `mdframed` environments and one footnote in the first one, it will be displayed in the second one. I would like the footnote to be displayed in the `mdframed` environment it belongs to. Is it possible?

Furthermore, there are inconstancies on the width of the second environment. Can anyone explain these strange facts?

### Code and picture

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}


\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = red, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 11cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]


Vestibulum\footnote{lectus metus} lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.



\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 135mm, 
backgroundcolor = blue, 
skipabove = 35mm, 
linewidth = 0pt, 
userdefinedwidth = 9cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 10mm, 
splittopskip = 10mm, 
roundcorner = 5pt, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
align = center]


Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

\end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has given a direct `mdframed` answer yet, I can offer an alternative approach using `tcolorbox` to solve the footnote problem.

The following code mimics your `mdframed` boxes. I excluded the large `skipabove` and `skipbelow` values, because I guess these are just for testing (?).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced,breakable,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
    grow to left by=-5mm,
    grow to right by=-5mm,
    colback=red]

  Vestibulum\footnote{lectus metus} lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

  \begin{tcolorbox}[
      enhanced,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,frame hidden,
      colback=blue]
    Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]